# Show or hide image on scroll interval

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to display a different image based on the user's scroll position but cant seem to get the last part working. (All vanillaJS and no jQ or plugins.)

Ie removing the hidden class when iArr[i] < rx.top && iArr[i] > (iArr[i]*2) or something like that.

This is probably not the best solution but the only way I know of.

Any ideas or advice on this?

```js
var entered, left, visible;

var images = [
  {
    src:
      "https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/70d6bbfc4ec4d0be406bd7a92d6a0c680616d68c/f1b7a/img/birch1.jpg"
  },
  {
    src:
      "https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/75b59ebb394c29c962ecbc77457ca18c02dab4be/bebd9/img/birch2.jpg"
  },

  {
    src:
      "https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/bc5b281554d2013bd5f43983d506268622364066/39b1a/img/birch3.jpg"
  },

  {
    src:
      "https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/b1c21fcbe2688cae0df5c95b613cd1d15928aac1/8b616/img/birch4.jpg"
  },

  {
    src:
      "https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/bbf49ae00cef82d8df2c907f696ac05cafca17a9/e6af0/img/birch5.jpg"
  },
  {
    src:
      "https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/70d6bbfc4ec4d0be406bd7a92d6a0c680616d68c/f1b7a/img/birch1.jpg"
  },
  {
    src:
      "https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/75b59ebb394c29c962ecbc77457ca18c02dab4be/bebd9/img/birch2.jpg"
  },

  {
    src:
      "https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/bc5b281554d2013bd5f43983d506268622364066/39b1a/img/birch3.jpg"
  },

  {
    src:
      "https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/b1c21fcbe2688cae0df5c95b613cd1d15928aac1/8b616/img/birch4.jpg"
  },

  {
    src:
      "https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/bbf49ae00cef82d8df2c907f696ac05cafca17a9/e6af0/img/birch5.jpg"
  }
  ,

  {
    src:
      "https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/b1c21fcbe2688cae0df5c95b613cd1d15928aac1/8b616/img/birch4.jpg"
  },

  {
    src:
      "https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/bbf49ae00cef82d8df2c907f696ac05cafca17a9/e6af0/img/birch5.jpg"
  }
];

//Add images array to inner div
var inner = document.getElementById("inner");
//Add unique classes to images
images.forEach(function(el, idx) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = el.src;
  img.classList.add("img", "hidden", "img-" + idx);
  // console.log(img)
  inner.appendChild(img);
});


window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  var rx = inner.getBoundingClientRect();
  //console.log(rx.height)
  var imgCount = images.length;//12
  //console.log(imgCount)

  //Get the viewport height and divide by total number of images
  var scrollImageBottom = rx.height / imgCount;
  var interval = rx.height / images.length;
  //console.log(interval)
  var newArr = [];

  for (var i = 1; i <= imgCount; i++) {
    newArr.push(i*interval);
    //newArr.reverse();
  }
  var iArr = newArr.reverse();
  console.log(iArr);
  console.log(rx.top);
  
  //Something like this
  
  // if ( iArr[i] < rx.top && iArr[i] > (iArr[i]*2) ) {
  //   iArr[i].node. removeClass('hidden');
  // }
  // else {
  //   iArr[i].node.addClass('hidden')
  // }

  
  if (rx.top <= rx.height && rx.bottom >= 0 && !entered) {
    entered = true;
    console.log("in viewport");
  }

  if (
    (rx.bottom <= rx.height && rx.bottom <= 0 && !left) ||
    (rx.top >= rx.height && rx.bottom <= 0 && !left)
  ) {
    left = true;
    entered = false;
    visible = false;
    console.log("left viewport");
  }
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
.wrapper{
  height: 400vh;
}
.inner{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position:absolute;
  top:150vh;
  background:red;
  border:2px solid red;
}
.img{
  position: absolute;
  width:auto;
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Scroll down and check console</h1>
  <div id="inner" class="inner">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371552/changing-background-image-onscroll

Comment: Thanks @ChintuYadavSara but this is not the same. I have an array of images that needs to be compared to and array of scroll values. The above example deals with 2 images that is shown/hidden based on a fixed scroll position.